# How to get combined result of Multiple Arrays ( 3 to 5 Arrays ) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Input is an array of objects that has a value of array?
The arrays can be 4 to 5 or even more
i want the output to be something like below, ( an array of objects that has mixed value of the parent array)

So the Input is

```
var all = [
  {
    name: "size",
    value: [20, 10, 5],
  },
  {
    name: "color",
    value: ["red", "black"],
  },
  {
    name: "width",
    value: [500, 600],
  },
];
```

and the output should be like this:

```
var output = [
  { size: 20, color: "red", width: 500 },
  { size: 20, color: "red", width: 600 },
  { size: 20, color: "black", width: 500 },
  { size: 20, color: "black", width: 600 },
  { size: 10, color: "red", width: 500 },
  { size: 10, color: "red", width: 600 },
  { size: 10, color: "black", width: 500 },
  { size: 10, color: "black", width: 600 },
  { size: 5, color: "red", width: 500 },
  { size: 5, color: "red", width: 600 },
  { size: 5, color: "black", width: 500 },
  { size: 5, color: "black", width: 600 },
];
```

Comment: so, there's only ever size/color/width?

Comment: there could be more

Comment: color: "red" it should be a string sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a recursive problem:

```js
const arrAll = 
  [ { name: 'size',  value: [ 20, 10, 5]      } 
  , { name: 'color', value: [ 'red', 'black'] } 
  , { name: 'width', value: [ 500, 600]       } 
  ] 

const output = []

function f_arrange (arr,idx,item)
  {
  if ( idx < arr.length)
    {
    arr[idx].value.forEach( v =>
      {
      let obj = Object.assign( {}, item,{ [arr[idx].name]: v} ) 
      f_arrange(arr,idx+1,obj)
      })
    }
  else
    output.push(item)
  }

f_arrange(arrAll,0,{})

console.log( output )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

> refactorized code for cleanest usage

```js
const arrAll = 
  [ { name: 'size',  value: [ 20, 10, 5]      } 
  , { name: 'color', value: [ 'red', 'black'] } 
  , { name: 'width', value: [ 500, 600]       } 
  ] 

const output = f_arrange( arrAll )

console.log( output )

function f_arrange( arr )
  {
  const
    ret = []
  , len = arr.length
    ;
  agreger(0,{})
  return ret

  function agreger(idx,item)
    {
    if (idx < len)
      arr[idx].value.forEach( v =>
        agreger( idx+1, Object.assign( {}, item, { [arr[idx].name]: v} )))
    else 
      ret.push(item)
    }
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your website/application supports ES6, you can do this easily by spreading the arrays into a new one:
`const output = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3];`

Otherwise, a working but less elegant solution is to use `concat()`:
`var output = arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3)`